# Autoplay in Chromium Browser

Tags: html, html5-audio, autoplay

I've been trying to play a sound when I'm in PHP in an IF loop for a long time and I've already tried a lot and then gave up because I heard it doesn't work in Chromium Browser.

I've tried various workarounds but these don't seem to work with newer versions or I'm too stupid for it ( run as video, run muted and so on)

I am of course aware of the reasons why this is no longer allowed. It would also be possible for me if the user had to confirm this sound beforehand.

is there really no working solution?

I very much appreciate your help.

Ive tried:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

multiple tries with an video tag  and various stackoverflow trys

.It would be fine for me that the user on the page agrees to play it, but since the page reloads every x seconds and checks whether there is a database entry, he would have to agree every time, right?